# Implications of the $\Omega(\frac{2^n}{n})$ circuit lower bound being tight

Tags: complexity-theory, lower-bounds, circuits

There is a basic result in circuit complexity that says:

> There exists a language that cannot be solved with circuits of size $o(\frac{2^n}{n})$.

The argument is a simple counting argument on the number of boolean functions and the number of distinct circuits.  See, for example, [these lecture notes](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs254-14/lecture03.pdf).

I believe it is unknown whether or not this bound is tight.  That is, we don't know if the following statement is true:

> Every language can be solved with circuits of size $O(\frac{2^n}{n})$.

If this statement were true, would it have any interesting implications for complexity theory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been proved by [Muller](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5219786) as early as 1956. Here is the construction. Let $k$ be a parameter. We first compute *all* possible functions on the first $k$ inputs in size $O(2^{2^k})$ (see below). We then construct a decision tree for the other $n-k$ variables, connecting it to the correct function on the remaining variables. This takes $O(2^{n-k})$ (see below), for a total of $O(2^{2^k}) + O(2^{n-k})$. Choosing $k = \log (n - \log n)$, we obtain the desired bound.

We compute all possible functions on $k$ inputs inductively. Let $Z_k$ be the size of a circuit computing all possible functions on $k$ inputs. There are two functions on zero inputs, so $Z_0 = 2$. Every function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ on $k$ inputs can be written as $x_k f(x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1},1) + \overline{x_k} f(x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1},0)$, so $Z_k = Z_{k-1} + 2^{2^k} \cdot O(1)$. The solution of this recurrence is $Z_k = O(2^{2^k})$.

In order to compute the decision tree, we use a similar construction: given a tree $T$ for the first $k-1$ variables, we can construct a tree for the first $k$ variables of the form $x_k T + \overline{x_k} T$. The recurrence we get is $W_k = 2W_{k-1} + O(1)$, whose solution is $W_k = O(2^k)$.

Comment: I understood the construction of the decision tree and of the circuit computing all possible outputs, but couldn't quite understand how combining them yields a circuit for $f$. Would you mind elaborating on that a little more?

Comment: See Theorem 1.5 here: https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/cs294-2018/hardest-fns.pdf.