# Circuit complexity of random Boolean functions

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

I just saw a YouTube video where Ryan Williams gives a talk about circuit complexity. He stated that random Boolean functions require exponential size circuits to compute, but I don't understand why this would be so. Can someone explain this aspect of circuit complexity for me? Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a link to the original source (the video you mentioned).

Comment: If I recall correctly, it's a counting argument: you count the number of circuits of size $\le s$, then that's an upper bound on the number of Boolean functions that can be computed using a circuit of size $\le s$, and you compare that to the total number of Boolean functions.  See, e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23365/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/72483/755 for related results.

Comment: https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/cs294-2018/hardest-fns.pdf

Comment: It may be helpful to you. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72483/function-that-cannot-be-computed-by-a-boolean-circuit-of-size-2n-2n/72484#72484